# Restricting protcols in SSLContext

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, httpclient

I have a java server using SSLv3 protocol via tomcat.

I am creating a java client which will just communicate using SSLv3. Additionally i am using Apache Http client for my http communication. Below is the snippet of the client code i am using,

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
TrustManager[] trustManagers = getTrustManagers("jks", new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\SSLKeyStore.ks")), "changeit");
ctx.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
System.out.println("Context Protocol - " + ctx.getProtocol());

SSLSocketFactory factory = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
factory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

ClientConnectionManager manager = httpClient.getConnectionManager();
manager.getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 443, factory));

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://localhost:8844/getData");

System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
```

Problem is when i enable '`javax.net.debug=ssl'`, in the logs i see, my client talking TLSv1, while my server is correctly communicating via SSLv3. Below is what the logs look like,

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
main, READ: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 1353
*** ServerHello, SSLv3
```

When i print the supported protocols, i see "SSLv3, TLSv1", and hence i guess the client is showing a higher version protocol.

But the question here is how do i restrict the client to use only "SSLv3". I have also tried setting `https.protocols="SSLv3"`. But this too hasn't helped.

Looking for any solutions/tips that might help.

Thanks in advance.

Vicky

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this.

If i subclass the `SSLSocketFactory` and override `createSocket` method to `"setEnabledProtocols"` to `'SSLv3'`. Then the communication is exactly as given, i.e. both client and server communicate using `SSLv3`.

Below is the debug exchange,

```
*** ClientHello, SSLv3
***
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 149
main, READ: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 1353
*** ServerHello, SSLv3
```

However i am open to any other approaches there are, which are more subtle.